# Print_r returns what I want but echo does not

Tags: php, arrays, echo, stdclass

I am trying to get the first "url" from what I think is an array.

This get the "url" works fine but it not usable obviously

```
print_r ($wantedimage[0]);
```

But this gets error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

When I try

```
echo $wantedimage[0];
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: it already says you cannot echo a whole object, maybe echo its property instead. `echo $wantedimage[0]->url;`

Comment: Could you please add the result, you getting on print_r? That way we can see what your object is!

Comment: Could you do a `var_Dump` of `$wantedimage`. That will allow us to help more precisely :)

Comment: all the fingers are waiting for that `print_r/var_dump` results :p

Comment: To address what the others are saying, `echo` only works on simple (numeric/string) types; your `$wantedimage` appears to be an Array, and the items within the array are Objects.  It would be easier to direct you if we saw the results of your `print_r` statement, but what @Ghost states is likely true.

Comment: Print_r returns lots of different ones of these. Slightly obfuscated to protect client data. 

stdClass Object ( [id] => 1234 [version] => 2 [number] => 100x100 [width] => 100 [height] => 100 [url] => http:/blabla100x100.jpg [secure] => )

Comment: @JustinBell, think it is more fishy than that. `print_r($object)` or `print_r($stdClass)` would just echo out something like `StdClass Object x => y)` defently `$wantedimage[>>0<<]` is wrong.

Comment: So, have you tried `print_r ($wantedimage)`? I'm having trouble understanding this question and the way it's asked.

Comment: I am trying to delete the question as I cant give enough info to help answer it.

Comment: You can flag your own question and give specific instructions as to why it should be deleted. Or, ask the others to delete their answers first, then you can delete your question. Only if everyone agrees to delete their answers.

Comment: Thanks. Using this site compared to others is frustrating sometimes. Its too strict.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not that it's too strict, we try to help the best we can, yet sometimes certain problems are much harder to solve than others. You need to give this site a chance. We can't solve all of them sometimes. There is information lacking that people need to know what it is, how it is being used, where the data is coming from and in which format. It could be a simple fix, or not.

Comment: Sorry I was just frustrated. Would of maybe been easier if I could of uploaded the var_dump for you guys but its not my data to do that with anyway so not your fault.

Comment: worked it out with the help given here and posted an answer below so dont know if the admin will want to keep the question or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out with help from the answers here and my own tenacity.

This worked for some reason. So please do not delete question as I flagged for if it is useful.

```
$wantedimage =$data-> images;

$a0=$wantedimage[0]->url;

echo $a0;
```

Thanks for the help.

Sorry I was so stressed about it. It's part of a bigger code with many nested levels.

Answer (score 4):

You should use something like this:

```
foreach($wantedimage as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value;
}
```

Or based on it's structure:

```
$wantedimage[0]->url
```

Comment: thanks but not working for me because its not an array apparently. Weirdly seems to be neither an array or a stdClass unless I am mistaken. although the Print_r shows the structure of an array obviously.

Comment: Can you show us the output of print_r($wantedimage) ?

Comment: Print_r returns lots of different ones of these. Slightly obfuscated to protect client data. stdClass Object ( [id] => 1234 [version] => 2 [number] => 100x100 [width] => 100 [height] => 100 [url] => http:/blabla100x100.jpg [secure] => )

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook - `$wantedimage->url` ?

Comment: I think it is a malformed JSON that the data is coming from, In which case there may be no solution. Hence why I have requested the question to be closed. Attempts at help were appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `var_dump` or [Kint](https://kint-php.github.io/kint/).
And also `$wantedimage[0]`, what's the type of this? Integer, Float, String, Array, ..., What?

Comment: Its a string. A URL for an image. why use var_dump and not print_r like I already have?

Comment: Do `<?php var_dump($wantedimage);` and give us the results.

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook, bacause a var_dump would provide the nessecary information to solve the problem :) There is defently going something on ...

Comment: Var dump is too long for here. Contracting it just creating more errors. Cheers for trying.

Comment: Tried to delete question but it wont let me.